# Is there a difference in SAS proc sql between inner join and just listing two tables in the from statement with a filter for the key?

Tags: sql, join, sas, proc-sql

To be clear, I'm not asking about the difference between an inner join and a union or something. I'm talking about two methods of joining tables. For example (using SAS EG 9.4):

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select [fields here]
    from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
        on t1.key=t2.key
    where [filters here];
quit;
```

vs.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select [fields here]
    from table1 as t1, table2 as t2
    where t1.join_key=t2.join_key
        and [filters here];
quit;
```